# Recieving a text file from Bluetooth in an Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to receive a text file from another Android device which will send an reading in text file format and I want to read it and store it in an database, I have done the reading and storing part but I am not able to understand how to receive the file via Bluetooth and read that text file

I am getting all the code for sending the file, but not to receive a text file. I have tried a lot of code but it's not doing what I need.

The following is my code to read the text file:

```
String []message=null;

    BufferedReader br=null;
    String name1, faculty1, deparment1, officeNumber1, email1, phone1, gl1, bp1;
    long e;
    try{
        String sCurrentLine = null;

        br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("1.txt")));


        while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if(sCurrentLine != null )

                message=sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");

            faculty1 = message[0];
            deparment1 = message[1];
            name1 = message[2];
            officeNumber1 = message[3];
            gl1 = message[4];
            bp1 = message[5];
            phone1 = message[6];

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
            values.put(hr, faculty1);
            values.put(rr, deparment1);
            values.put(spo2, name1);
            values.put(hb, officeNumber1);
            values.put(time, phone1);
            values.put(gl, gl1);
            values.put(bp, bp1);
            Log.w("aa", faculty1);
            Log.w("aa", gl);
            Log.w("aa", bp);
            dataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, values);
            updateTextView();
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/orium-dev/BluetoothChat

Answer (score 0):

You can try client server architecture. Make sending device as client and receiving device as server.